# Expected a value of type 'Map<String, String?>', but got one of type 'Null in flutter after upgrading to null safety

Tags: flutter, dart

I had Project, which was working very well. I upgraded it to null safety.
Now I'm getting the `Expected a value of type 'Map<String, String?>', but got one of type 'Null`.

Here is the code before the upgrading to null safety:

```
final Map<String, String> args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

which is working fine.

And here is the code after upgrading to null safety.

```
final Map<String, String?> args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String?>;
```

which gives the error
Dose any know why? and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ModalRoute.of(context)` may be null for that reason you used `!` on it so it may cause `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments` be null but you expect non-null `Map`, so change this:

```
final Map<String, String?> args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String?>;
```

to this:

```
 final Map<String, String?>? args =
    ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map<String, String?>?;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I got the ```A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, String?>?'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, String?>?'.``` error

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @Davood

Comment: still my original error is there

Comment: sorry I forgot to change `!` to `?`. check out my new I update.

Comment: first of all the error is still there, and second of all I think, ```settings`` can't be nullable